# how do i turn echo on and off

Tags: batch-file, virtual-machine

I am building a virtual machine for windows but the vm is for ms-dos.

1. My batch file should be able to process user input
2. The comannd prompt should start  `C:`  drive instead of `C:/users/YOURNAME`
3. i dont want it to show that command

To fix 3.) i tried echo off

How can i adress 1.) and 2.) use a macro for user based input?

Here is my code

```
@echo off
echo This is mosdos virtual machine
cd C:
@echo on
```

Comment: You've turned `echo` on and off in you code already. If you're confused by the fact that you typed `@echo off` and then the next `echo` displayed something, it's because `@echo off` just means "don't show the command before you run the command." If you want to suppress output, but a `>nul` at the end of your command.

Comment: You think DOS is just a batch file? Ever take an operating systems class where you needed to build your own os.  Was required back in the 80' and 90's when I was in college.

Comment: `cd C:` doesn't do what you think it does. Use `cd /`. Batch is not ms-dos, ms-dos is a 32 bit OS. You are probably thinking of cmd.exe which is sometimes known as ms-dos but is definitely not.

Comment: Echo off means don't echo _user input_. `SetConsoleMode` `ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT` Characters read by the `ReadFile` or `ReadConsole` function are written to the active screen buffer as they are read. This mode can be used only if the `ENABLE_LINE_INPUT` mode is also enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolemode

Comment: @NekoMusume: DOS is a 16-bit OS, based on 8-bit code.

Comment: Use `cd /D C:\ `instead of `cd C:`. Then open a Command Prompt window and type `echo /?`. Note that *echo* means *command echo*, so when echo is on, every parsed command is, well, echoed before it is executed. You can avoid echo of a specific command when you precede it with `@`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well yes, you can use Macro's for user input / output in Batch scripting, the syntax is just different from what you may be expecting.

Here is an example of a macro for handling user input:

```bat
@Echo off
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion

    (Set LF=^


    %= Above Empty lines Required =%)

    Set ^"\n=^^^%LF%%LF%^%LF%%LF%^^"

::: { %@I_O%<[Var Name]>,<[/O Output Var] [/S Set Var]>,<[Prompt for /S Set /P]>
    Set @I_O=For %%n in (1 2) Do if "%%n" == "2" (%\n%
        For /F "Tokens=1,2,3 Delims=," %%G in ("!Param!") Do (%\n%
            IF "%%~H" == "/O" (ECHO/%%G = !%%~G!)%\n%
            IF "%%~H" == "/S" (Set %%~G=)%\n%
            IF "%%~H" == "/S" For /L %%# in (1 1 5) Do If "!%%~G!" == "" (Set /P "%%~G=%%~I ")%\n%
        )%\n%
    ) Else Set Param=,
::: }
    Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:Example
    %@I_O%Name,/S,Enter your Name:
IF /I "!Name!" == "Exit" (Exit /B 0)
    %@I_O%Name,/O
Goto :Example
```

And an explanation of how it's constructed:

The LF escape character `^` is used to construct the `/n` Newline variable to allow multiline variable commands to be defined.

In order to define the Macro commands to process variables not yet defined, the Macro is defined in an environment with Delayed Expansion Disabled, allowing definition of 'Future Variables' within the macro.

The macro itself uses a nest of two `For` loops to 'capture' arguments via the If / Else construct in the outer `%%n` Loop, and the inner For loop breaks down those arguments into `tokens` using a delimiting character - `,` in this instance.

The Logic to be enacted with the arguments passed to the macro is contained in the heart of the nested loops.

Steps should be taken to validate user input prior to use of their content within scripts - In this example, A for /L loop with a conditional check regarding the variables definition has been used to promote definition of the variable, requiring the variable to be undefined prior to User Input.

Once the macro has been Defined, Delayed expansion needs to be enabled in order to use it.